# How to increase cell value with respect to another cell increment (Not decrements)

Tags: google-sheets

Here is example sheet it has two column "A" & "B" and two cells "A1" & "B1"

```
A        B
10       0


Now if     A1=11,      B1=11 
    if     A1=15,      B1=15

But if     A1=9,       B1=15
       (Decreased)    (No Change)

Again if   A1=18       B1=18

but if     A1=16       B1=18
```

All over if Column "A" Value increase Column "B" should have The value of column "A" But Should remain unchanged in if column A value decreased.

Comment: You need VBA or Apps Script to do this, depending on whether you're using Excel or Sheets respectively.

Comment: Does **A1** contain a *formula* or a *typed-in* value ??

Comment: A1 contains a Formula, which results a numeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem you have mentioned by using this Apps Script snippet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rangeB = sheet.getRange(1, 2);
  var valueA = e.range.getValue();
  if (e.range.getRow() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 1) 
    if (valueA () > e.oldValue)
     rangeB.setValue(valueA);
}
```

The above function makes use of the `onEdit(e)` installable trigger and event objects.

To install the trigger you should go to your project's triggers, click on the **Add trigger** icon and configure the trigger with the following settings:

[image: onEdit(e) settings]

The `e` event object has been used here in order to check if the `A1` cell has been modified. If the new value of the `A1` cell is larger than the previous one, then the `B1` cell is modified accordingly. In order to find the previous value of `A1` cell, the `e.oldValue` has been used.

#### Note

The above code monitors the change in the `A1` cell *only*; if all the cells in the `A` column have to be monitored, then changes need to be applied to the code in order to reflect that behavior.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below formula in B1:

```
=IF(A1<B1, B1, A1)
```

If you are using Google Sheets, you may get an error initially as shown below:

```
Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet settings.
```

You can correct this error by clicking File>Spreadsheet settings>Calculation tab>Iterative calculation is set to "On"

In excel, correcting circular references is a bit more labour intensive. Here's a guide you may refer:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123